# child process got killed while parent was blocked on read

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

What happens when the child process gets killed while the parent is blocked on read() from a pipe? How should I handle this scenario in parent process?

For clarification, parent process has two threads. Lets say thread1 was reading from the pipe when thread2 killed the child.

Will read() return -1?

Will appreciate any help here.

Comment: I suggest to share your code to increase your chance of receiving a respond. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Check out the man page for pipes:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html

Comment: You should at least put an effort to test your scenario. In the process, you will learn how it behaves, then you can ask if the behavior you see is consistent.

Comment: The same thing that happens whenever a child is killed.  Unless you have ignored it, the parent gets a SIGCHLD and the read returns -1 with errno set to EINTR, unless slow system calls aren't interruptible.  If the child happens to be the only process that holds the write end to the pipe, then read will return 0 when you retry it or immediately if it was not interruptible.  But, if you have a coding error and the parent still has on open copy of the write end of the pipe and is ignoring SIGCHLD then the parent will block indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe behavior has nothing to do with process relationships. The same rules apply regardless of whether the reader is the parent, child, sibling, or some other distant relation of the writer. Or even if the reader and writer are the same process.

The short answer is that death of a writing process is just an EOF from the reader's point of view, not an error, and this doesn't depend on whether the writing process voluntarily called `_exit()` or was killed by a signal.

The whole cause and effect chain goes like this:

1. Process X dies -> all of process X's file descriptors are closed.
2. One of process X's file descriptors was the write end of a pipe
3. A pipe write file descriptor is closed -> was it the last one?

3a. There are other write file descriptors on the same pipe (e.g. inherited by fork and still open in another process), nothing happens. Stop.

3b. There are no more write file descriptors for this pipe -> the pipe has hit EOF.

4. Pipe hits EOF -> readers notice.

4a. All read file descriptors for the pipe become readable, waking up any process that was blocking on `select` or `poll` or `read` or another similar syscall.

4b. If there is any leftover data in the pipe buffer (written before the last write file descriptor was closed), that data is returned to the reader(s).

4c. repeat 4b until the pipe buffer is empty

4d. Finally, `read()` returns 0, indicating EOF.

The exit status of a child process is returned to the parent by the `wait` family of syscalls, and you have to check that if you want to know when your child processes have been killed by a signal.